# Select or deselect with mouse gesture

Tags: mouse

I can do this easy on Blender 2.79 I just hold `Ctrl` and drag the mouse to select some vertices and `Ctrl` + `Shift` to deselect. How can ahieve this in Blender 2.8?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the box select is the default tool. You can select vertices just by selecting the tool. Use Shift to expand the selection and Ctrl to subtract. Switch tools on the menu. [image]

Answer (score 1):

To "draw select" like this in blender 2.8+, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> (hold). Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> to deselect.